# Copying a specific range of cells form multiple worksheets in a work book to a Summary Sheet

Tags: vba, macros

I have data on 28-31 different worksheets based on the month.  the data is goes from B23 to J33. I need to copy and paste those cells from each tab to a Summary tab.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you sure that you need to write a new macro and it is completely impossible to use built-in mechanisms, for example [**Consolidate data in multiple worksheets**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/consolidate-data-in-multiple-worksheets-007ce8f4-2fae-4fea-9ee5-a0b2c9e36d9b)?

Comment: I read about consolidate, but I don't want a calculation performed, like sum or average, I just want the raw data all together so I can make it a linked table in access.

Comment: Please add some sample input data and expected output to your question, so that we know what you're trying to do.